# Python conditional using regex with multiline string

Tags: python, regex

I need help with very simples question, a conditional using regex with multiline string. No make sense to me why this not work:

```
if(re.match(r"\w", " \n\n\n  aaaaaaaaaaaa\n\n", re.MULTILINE)):
    print('ok')
else:
    print('fail')

fail
```

I expected that result be **ok**, but no match any data. I trying using https://regex101.com/r/BsdymE/1, but there works and in my code not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re.match will only return a match if the search string is at the beginning.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match

> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

Try using `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)` instead

Answer (score 0):

From `pydoc re.match`:

> Try to apply the pattern **at the start of the string**, returning a
>   Match object, or None if no match was found.

(emphasis mine). So, the problem is not with the string being multiline, but rather with it not **beginning** with a word-class character. If you want to check if a string contains something anywhere, use `re.search` instead.